# Portable VirtualBox shared drive without a fixed drive letter

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, portable

I have installed VirtualBox portable onto a USB stick and created a virtual machine.

I want to share files between guest and host via a shared folder, but VirtualBox will not accept a folder of the format `\VM_shared`, relative to the drive root.

It only works if I specify a drive latter, such as `F:\VM_shared`, but by USB stick might not be assigned `F:` in every system that I insert it into.

I *could* just manually change the VM settings if that happens, but I would prefer a no-maintenence solution.

Can it be done?